# How to check if websocket connection is in readystate using "github.com/gorilla/websocket"

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I'm using the "github.com/gorilla/websocket" package in Golang and I want to know if my websocket connection is in OPEN state or in CONNECTING state.

The states that I want to know can be seen [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/readyState)

Comment: Is there a problem you are trying to solve by checking the state?

Answer (score 1):

The Gorilla package does not have the concept of these states, but here's a rough mapping from the browser states to Gorilla.

- The Dialer.Dial and Upgrader.Upgrade methods return a connection in the OPEN state.
- The connection is in the CLOSING state when read on the connection returns an error or the application sends a [close message](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#CloseMessage).
- The connection is in the CLOSED state after the application calls [Close()](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket#Conn.Close) on the connection.

Comment: So, is it safe to assume that if connection doesn't return any of the websocket close errors, then it is in open state ? And that connection can send and receive message.

Comment: @Vivek If your goal is to determine if a connection can send and receive messages, then ask that question.   The mapping to browser connection states is not relevant.